# how to passlatitude and longitude values dynamically to polyline path of googlemap in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am having an array like this [17.4172192,78.401285,17.418407,78.401629,17.41809,78.40061,17.417865,78.398234,17.405446,78.404805], i want to pass this JSONArray dynamically to the path of polyline in google maps.
When i pass latitude and longitude by static it was working fine, but in dynamic i have run a for loop it was not working please help me, here is my **javascript**,
In **request.getAttribute("latlongjson")** i am having the values are [17.4172192,78.401285,17.418407,78.401629,17.41809,78.40061,17.417865,78.398234,17.405446,78.404805]

```
<script>
          var poly;
      var map;
        var locations = <%= request.getAttribute("latlongjson") %>  ;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: {lat: 17.4172192, lng: 78.401285}  
        });

        // for polyline
 for (var i = 0, ln = locations.length; i < ln; i += 2) {
            poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path:[
                new google.maps.LatLng(latitide[i],latitude[i+1])
             ],
          strokeColor: '#0000FF',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
        });
   }

        poly.setMap(map);
   //   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      }

      }
    </script>
```

Anyone please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Are you missing a semi colon?
 var locations = <%= request.getAttribute("latlongjson") %>  ;

Comment: ya thats not a problem, it was working for markers with   this logic but not working for polyline                                                                                          for (var i = 0, ln = locations.length; i < ln; i += 2) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i], locations[i + 1]),
             map: map,
             title: locations[i]+", "+locations[i+1],
         });
       }

Comment: whate does console.log(locations) return?

Comment: I think its not necessary, eventhoug i have added i am not getting

Comment: path:[
                new google.maps.LatLng(latitide[i],latitude[i+1])
             ]

i dont see latitude or longitude array in your code.

Comment: [17.4172192,78.401285,17.418407,78.401629,17.41809,78.40061,17.417865,78.398234,17.405446,78.404805]   which will come with **request.getAttribute("latlongjson")**

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: latitide is not defined` (because it isn't defined)

Comment: You are creating a bunch of polylines each with a single point.

Comment: [17.4172192,78.401285,17.418407,78.401629,17.41809,78.40061,‌​17.417865,78.398234,‌​17.405446,78.404805] in above array [0] is latitude and [1] is longitude in the same  [2] is latitude and [3] is longitude etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

      var poly;
      var map;
       var locations = [
            17.4172192,78.401285,
            17.418407, 78.401629,
            17.418090, 78.400610,
            17.417865, 78.398234
            ]; 
    //  var locations = <%= request.getAttribute("latlongjson") %>  

        // for center the map   

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: {lat: 17.4172192, lng: 78.401285}  // Center the map on Chicago, USA.
        });


var flightPlanCoordinates = new Array();
for(i=0;i<locations.length;i += 2)
{  
  var point =new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i],locations[i+1]);
  flightPlanCoordinates.push(point);   
} 
alert(flightPlanCoordinates);


        // for polyline

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
       /*    path:[
                new google.maps.LatLng(17.4172192,78.401285),
                new google.maps.LatLng(17.418407, 78.401629),
                new google.maps.LatLng(17.418090, 78.400610),
                new google.maps.LatLng(17.417865, 78.398234) 
             ], */
             path : flightPlanCoordinates,
            // geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#0000FF',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
        });

        // for markers

        for (var i = 0, ln = locations.length; i < ln; i += 2) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i], locations[i + 1]),
              map: map,
              title: locations[i]+", "+locations[i+1],
          });
        }
        poly.setMap(map);
   //   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        // Add a listener for the click event
        map.addListener('click', addLatLng);
      }
}
</script>
```